# Laptop is suddenly making lots of programs crash and unrespond, any idea why?

Tags: windows-8.1, memory, crash

I have had this laptop since early last year, specs are:

```
CPU: Intel Core i3-3110M CPU @ 2.40GHz
RAM: 4.00 GB (3.88 GB usable)
System: 64-bit-OS, x64-based processor
OS: Windows 8.1
```

So yeah, not a very bad laptop either. However, recently it has suddenly being really slow sometimes, and even making any program crash or stop responding, including firefox, games, file explorer, MS Paint, task manager... LITERALLY everything.

My task manager looks like this, so is probably the issue:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/W4V4XLz.png]

As you can see, my Memory and disk usage is very high. What can I do about this? Nothing really is using much memory at all, I don't see how 90% of my 4gb ram is being used.

What can I do to help my PC be fine again?

Here is the resource manager memory tab

[image: http://i.imgur.com/sLGyrrl.png]

RAMAP:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/PzPa49H.png]

Comment: I can barely make out your screen shot, but it doesn't appear that you selected the option to display processes from all users. Find that option and enable it.

Comment: @CareyGregory I am the only user

Comment: @Matthew No, Modern operating systems have a number of system user accounts that are used to limit permissions of various processes and restrict the potential damage that can be done if a security bug is found and exploited. Many Windows processes run as `SYSTEM`, `LOCAL SERVICE`, `NETWORK SERVICE`, and several other internal accounts, even if you only have one "user" account (for yourself).

Comment: @DarthAndroid Posted a RAMMAP above or here http://i.imgur.com/PzPa49H.png

Comment: There we go. Your Non-Paged Pool is almost half your memory-- It shouldn't be. This is memory used by the kernel and drivers that can't be paged out to disk - Large Non-Paged Pools are often related to a memory leak of some sort in a driver.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24598/discussion-between-darth-android-and-matthew).

Answer (score 1):

Your disk is maxed out because your system did not shut down properly, and now the disk has to be checked for corruption. This will max out disk usage until the check is complete.

Comment: This doesn't explain why programs are crashing, and `checkdsk` should finish within an hour or less depending on disk size.

Comment: @CareyGregory I'm just going by the image he posted - `checkdsk` is maxing out the drive.

Answer (score 0):

you might have some background tasks running for some of the software
Clean up your PC with different options, and once its done, it will be faster than before.

1. Dont keep huge files on desktop (this takes up ram space. Pressing refresh doesnt have any effect on the RAM shrinking). Just maintain simple links to files
2. Clean up background tasks.   Goto -> ctrl+R -> run "msconfig"  -> uncheck the box at the startup tab which u think are not required. (Ex: google hangout, skype, google talk, etc, which starts in background and is not required for normal operations and other softwares start tasks)
3. To adjust all visual effects for best performance:

   Open Performance Information and Tools by clicking the Start button Picture of the Start button, and then clicking Control Panel. In the search box, type Performance Information and Tools, and then, in the list of results, click Performance Information and Tools.

   Click Adjust visual effects. Administrator permission required If you're prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.

   Click the Visual Effects tab, click Adjust for best performance, and then click OK. (For a less drastic option, select Let Windows choose what’s best for my computer.)
4. Defrag at times..
5. Restart regularly.
6. One imp note:  while installing some software tools, they usually come with some unnecessary add-on utility. be careful while installing and "uncheck" these installation, which arent useful. (one Ex: is the browser tool bar for some apps/plugins)

Edited:  Beautiful explanation on the slowing down of PC, programs, etc:  https://askleo.com/why_is_my_machine_slowing_down/

Comment: Windows automatically defragments itself since at least Windows 7. You do not need to do this manually. The size of files on your desktop does not affect RAM usage (The desktop is just a folder, like any other)

Comment: #1 is wrong, #4 is unnecessary, and #5 is also unnecessary.

Comment: I agree to other conventions. (#4 is unnecessary in win 7/8) , #5 is unnecessary if u have well known softwares.  Others might be leaky or faulty and over period of time, it might take up more space if not restarted ,  However, there seems to be agreement on the files in desktop and few others..   -- http://superuser.com/questions/30710/is-that-true-that-if-you-keep-bulky-files-on-the-desktop-then-windows-slow-down

Answer (score 0):

You should post some better internal info > Like [Speccy](https://www.piriform.com/speccy), which offers specs, temperature, SMART, etc... more than a simple task manager screenshot.

Alternatively, there are basic things you can do to diagnose/fix a slow computer. Here's a list of tutorials, programs, etc... you should checkout.

~ [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/CCLEANER)
~ Remove known junk using [Revo](http://www.revouninstaller.com/)
~ WinKey+R `services.msc` and/or `taskschd.msc`
* Remove/disable unnecessary and reoccurring tasks.
* Remove/disable unwanted services. Do **not** mess with anything you're uncertain about. Only the obvious ones that are related to adware, crapware, or utilities you've knowingly removed in the past but may still be lingering.

~ You can't use `msconfig` with Win 8 so instead go to the "Startup" tab available now in the task manager. Disable excessive/unwanted startup progs from there.

Did you manually run `chkdsk`? Whether manually or automatically, it's happening for a reason. HDD failure can absolutely cause "crashes" and a dramatic decrease in performance so I suggest running **a** (bootable) HDD diagnostic tool like the following:

[HDDRegen](http://www.dposoft.net/hdd.html), [HDAT2](http://www.hdat2.com/), [MHDD](http://hddguru.com/software/2005.10.02-MHDD/), [SpinRite](https://www.grc.com/sr/spinrite.htm), [Hiren's BootCD](http://www.hirensbootcd.org/), etc.. which may or may not fix the "slow" issue entirely, that depends on the severity though. Regardless, running one of them will offer more info.

Otherwise, if you don't want to make a simple bootable diagnostic tool you can post the results of [CrystalDiskInfo](http://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskInfo/index-e.html)

EDIT: Dude, in your photo of `ResMon` you're running OSBuddy (a video game?), MalwareBytes (a scan?), Skype, FireFox and you're wondering about why your RAM has high usage? Skype, by default installation, starts on starup. You should change that using above suggestions. MBAM shouldn't be running 100% of the time in my opinion, then again I don't need AntiVirus software.

Comment: I am trying the Revo thing now. After I installed it and ran the exe in the download folder, it took a good 5-7 mins for the installation to even prompt me (As in, asking me if I want to install this)

Comment: Revo is 1/15 things I suggested. Have you tried anything else beyond that? Revo individually isn't going to solve anything so I recommend trying more before posting the same symptoms.

Comment: P.S. Specifically the suggestions that are native to windows, ie: `taskschd.msc`, startup tab, `sfc`, or portable progs. Seeing as how they aren't as demanding as Revo (which shouldn't actually be a big deal) and as result may run faster than 3rd party progs. Given the extreme amount of time that Revo took to load, I'm leaning towards some HDD related issue. So I strongly consider diagnosing that first.

Comment: Another user suggested I download "RAMMAP" and he found "Your Non-Paged Pool is almost half your memory-- It shouldn't be. This is memory used by the kernel and drivers that can't be paged out to disk - Large Non-Paged Pools are often related to a memory leak of some sort in a driver."    And he is looking into what I can do about this.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/PzPa49H.png

Comment: I am trying the nativve windows suggestions meanwhile

Comment: Yes, but they don't take up more than 1-1.3gb total of my memory, doesn't expliain where the other 2gb s have gone

Comment: Solved it man, turns out I had an unpaged pool memory leak, just needed to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SiYkfrLrJoE this